# Bootstrap Carousel: Data Slide symbols are missing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

When building up a simple template for Bootstrap's carousel, the ">" symbols are missing. You can easily spot [them in the documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel). Do I have to provide them somewhere? If yes, how and where?
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='de'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>XX</title>
    <meta content='' name='keywords' />
    <meta content='' name='description'>
      <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </meta>
    <link href='css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link href='img/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon' />
    <link href='css/bootstrap.min.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='carousel slide' id='myCarousel'>
        <div class='carousel-inner'>
          <div class='active item'>
            <a href='#'>
              <img src='img/slide-01.jpg' />
            </a>
            <div class='carousel-caption'>
              <p class='lead'>
                XX
              </p>
              <a class='btn btn-large btn-primary' href='#'>
                XX
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <a href='#'>
              <img src='img/slide-02.jpg' />
            </a>
            <div class='carousel-caption'>
              <p class='lead'>
                XX
              </p>
              <a class='btn btn-large btn-primary' href='#'>
                XX
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class='carousel-control left' data-slide='prev' href='#myCarousel'></a>
        <a class='carousel-control right' data-slide='next' href='#myCarousel'></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
  <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
      !function ($) {
        $(function(){
          var $window = $(window)
          $('#myCarousel').carousel('')
        })
      }(window.jQuery)
    //]]>
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working carousel to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/VuSqQ/

Note that the slide controls are specifying the character for the arrowheads

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Sometimes I need my rubber duck back.

Comment: ... I have several, I'll send you one of mine ;)